# magento getLoadedProductCollection is empty

Tags: magento-1.7, product-collection

I'm trying to create a block in controller from block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and use `getLoadedProductCollection()` but it is always empty

```
    $productList_block  = Mage::app()->getLayout()
                         ->createBlock('catalog/product_list');        
    $collection = $productList_block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $collection->clear();
    $_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

    $collection->setOrder('entity_id','asc');
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(100, 0);
    $collection->load();

    $select=$collection->getSelect();
    echo "select =".$select."\n";

    $l=0;
    foreach($collection as $_product){
       echo ++$l." --- ".$_product->getName()."\n";
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of `$select` and did you try running the query manually in your DB?

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

```
$productList_block  = Mage::app()->getLayout()
                     ->createBlock('catalog/product_list');        
$collection = $productList_block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$collection->clear();
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

$collection->setOrder('entity_id','asc');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(100, 0);
$collection->load();

$select=$collection->getSelect();
echo "select =".$select."\n";

$l=0;
foreach($collection as $_product){
   echo ++$l." --- ".$_product->getName()."\n";
}
```

You had an **undefined** `$_productCollection`.

However, I also found that the above will not work if you're running this in admin store context or if it's a standalone bootstrap file that sets the current store ID to the Admin store ID.

Bottom line - be careful with what you're doing here as it may or may not be violating best practice depending on where you're executing this.

I would prefer not to load a catalog block and layout just so that I can gain access to this method - rather recreate it with resource model calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your product collection in `$collection` and clearing it so it becomes null.

And there is no variable `$_productCollection` assigned in your code, replace it with `$collection`.

So the final code should be:

```
    $productList_block  = Mage::app()->getLayout()
                         ->createBlock('catalog/product_list');        
    $collection = $productList_block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    //$collection->clear();
    $collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);

    $collection->setOrder('entity_id','asc');
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(100, 0);
    $collection->load();

    $select=$collection->getSelect();
    echo "select =".$select."\n";

    $l=0;
    foreach($collection as $_product){
       echo ++$l." --- ".$_product->getName()."\n";
    }
```